# WITH vs Consumer Groups - performance and other considerations

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

I want to know  what are the performance implications of a WITH ? Should I prefer to depend as much as possible on a WITH clause ?

For example, if I have queries that look like that :

```
Select * from Input1 i where i.type = 'something'

Select * from Input1 i where i.type = 'something-else'

Select * from Input1 i where i.type = 'something-else' and i.cost > 500 

Select * from Input1 i where i.size < 10
```

a. Should I have a WITH on everything from Input1 just to limit the readers ? And do the other filtering as a second step. I'm guessing this would hurt performance.

b. Shouldn't I just create a consumer group per query ? Why not ?

c. A bit different, is there a relation between the performance of different outputs ? Does it matter if I have several outputs, where part of them are high throughput CosDb collections, and part are a Table storage ? Though the table storage is much better partitioned. Would it be better to separate the two to different (input, consumer group ) pairs, or even completely different ASA jobs?

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: for most typical workloads, you should be fine with a WITH statement to reduce the number of receivers. If you want to fine tune performances, you may create different inputs with different receivers.

Please find the detailed answers below:

a) For the first question, using WITH and then doing the filtering in that step will not impact performance for this query.

b) With the WITH statement, you can reduce the number of receivers needed. However if you need to have a larger number of receivers, you will have to define several inputs, and a different CG for each input. The pros/cons of the 2 approaches will depend of different factors such as the degree of parallelization/partitioning of the query, the volume and distribution of data, etc. You may have to experiment if you have a very high throughput, and use perf numbers and the "job diagram" to guide your decisions. Note that for most current jobs, you should be fine with the WITH statement.

c) If the pipelines are completely independent, you may want to create different jobs to maximize performances. You can use the "job diagram" of your ASA job to visualize your job topology and optimize it.

Let me know if it answers your question.

Thanks,

JS

Comment: First, thanks a bunch for answering. I will need a bit of time to write some tools to allow me test the performance. Is there a way for me to measure the running time of an ASA query ? Or ASA + output writing or something like that. At the moment, I thought of adding a trigger to CosDB to note insert time and compare it to the different timestamps left on the data by ASA and etc. My input is an IoT Hub so it can be partitioned and consumer grouped (?) like an EventHub, I'm not yet sure of the performance implications of partitioning or adding many consumer groups to an IoT Hub

Comment: What do you mean degree of parallelization/partitioning, how does it affect this ? It would be nice to know what the WITH statement actually does. Does it keep the result in memory ? What are the cons of having many consumer groups ? Besides the bother of creating them.

Comment: It seems like a good way to measure performance of your E2E flow. The WITH is way to tell the query optimizer to group the calls to that input together instead of doing them in parallel. Since your examples of queries are pretty simple, I don't think you will have any performance impact. If you have complex queries (JOIN, etc.) , you may have to keep them running in parallel. You can about scaling ASA jobs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-scale-jobs